# How do I play Halo 4 against bots?

Tags: halo-4

I would really like to know how to play Halo 4 "slayer" against computer bots. I have looked at many different sites and can not find anything that is relevant to my question.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is not possible. The only way to play any Halo 4 multiplayer mode is against other people.

Answer (score 0):

Halo 4 does not have a "vs bots" options, however there are co-op modes of Spartan Ops and even the entire campaign can be played in co-op.